# HTML no break when expected

Tags: html

I've got a strange splitting bug in a website I am making. Everywhere on the website the text is split in the correct way. But in one block it isn't.

http://www.spanjevakantiewinkel.nl/

At the bottom: "aankomende evenementen". Bunol, the last words are under the words of the next block! But all CSS of these blocks is the same.

I have no idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text content of that paragraph has `&nbsp;` (probably `\u00A0` in the original data) between the last words instead of normal spaces. Get rid of those and it will line break correctly.

Comment: Damn, I must have been asleep when I was asking this. The answer is sooo logic. I looked at the source with the Google Chrome debugger, and that didn't show non-braking-spaces, but the source of the content did! Simple answer, but correct. Thanks!